# MySQL: Find missing values within an IN clause

Tags: mysql

How to identify missing records from a list of items in an IN clause in MySQL?

**Given this DB:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `animals` (
  `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `animals` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'dog'),
  ('2', 'mouse'),
  ('3', 'cat'),
  ('4', 'snail');
```

**Using a query like:**

```
... NOT IN ("horse", "donkey", "dog");
```

**Should return:**

```
"horse", "donkey"
```

Is it even possible in MySQL **without creating a new temporary table** with the elements in the IN clause?

Of course I can use many programming languages (or even Excel sheets/formulas) to get the missing results but I am looking for a simple/pretty native MySQL method (if it exists).

**SQL Fiddle:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24eac7/3

Comment: How it should return `"horse", "donkey"` ? It will just return what the query is saying `NOT IN ("horse", "donkey", "dog")` means `mouse,cat,snail`

Comment: I guess instead of looking at what is not in your name array you could get the names that do exist and then in your code iterate the names array for ones that dont exist, if you dont want a temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if you are willing to use a derived table, which ever way you need the data to exist to return it.

```
 SELECT b.name FROM
 (
SELECT 'dog' name
UNION SELECT 'horse'
UNION SELECT 'donkey'
 ) b
LEFT JOIN animals a ON a.name = b.name
WHERE
  a.Name IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks but this is ugly and would be uglier if the records in the IN clause are large.

Comment: This is the only way I can think of for MySQL there are cleaner was in MSSQL or Postgres using the VALUES() syntax on an inner join

Comment: @numediaweb Relational databases are for the storage and retrieval of data. So, you have to choose between storing the data, and having an 'ugly' query.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way is using the ugly query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT list.name FROM (
  (SELECT 'horse' AS name) UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'donkey' AS name) UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'dog' AS id)
) AS list
LEFT JOIN animals ON list.name = animals.name
WHERE animals.name IS NULL
```

You could use PHP/Python/... to generate the query.

Comment: Thanks but I'am looking for something native to MySQL.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no solution. The reason is simple. SQL processes the given tables and produces a certain result. If there are NO values in ANY tables given, there is just no way to get those in the result.